# def function and offset

Tags: python, function, row, offset

I don't really understand `def` function. I'm trying to `return` a value in a different `cell` once my `string` is found and nothing is printing out so I believe I'm not setting up the `def` function correctly.

If I remove `def` and return and change `TA` to `TA= obj.value` the script will find my `string` and print it out so I know that portion works. Once I added in `def` and `return` and changed `TA` to `TA=obj.offset` it's not working.  There aren't any errors, it's just not printing out anything.

```
TFile = xl.load_workbook(T)
Sheet = TFile.worksheets[0]

String=pd.read_excel(input_file, usecols="A",nrows=1,header=None,squeeze=True).str.slice(start=28,stop=-2).to_string(index=False).strip()

def TA(String):
 for cellObj in Sheet['B2:B10000']:
  for obj in cellObj:
     if (obj.value) == String:
       return obj.offset(column=2, row=6).value
       TA = obj.offset
 print(TA)
```

Comment: You have placed the return statement within a for loop. Your function will return the first time the loop is entered and when the if condition evaluates to True. You probably want to return the function *after* the loop has completed? Or do you really want to *break* the loop? Furthermore: the code never reaches `TA = obj.offset` because the function returns just before that.

Comment: How do I return the function after the loop has completed?

Comment: By placing it outside the loop. In other words, decrease the indentation.

Comment: I need to be able to see what is being returned, and  I though by defining TA=obj.offset  I would be able to then use the returned value to search for it in another file.

Comment: When I decrease the indentation is says "expected an indented block"

Comment: Sorry, because you are reading a file which I don't have, with a module (pandas) I don't have, using a Sheet variable that I don't have, it is very difficult to give you a concrete answer. To learn more about functions in Python, I suggest to google for some tutorials.